# Django - How can I add a user to an auth_group?

Tags: django, django-users, django-permissions

I have and django application that I am trying to apply user group permissions. Here is how my members model is setup.

```
Class Member(AbstractUser)
    Class Meta:
        permissions = ((Perm1_codename, Perm1_desc),...)

pass
address = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

When I migrate this, the permissions are saved in the auth_group_permissions table instead of the members_app_member_user_permissions table. I don't see a way to associate a user to the auth_group table because there is no user column in these tables.

I setup my roles in auth_group and defined the permission of each role in auth_group_permissions, how can I associate a user to these groups?

Alternatively, how can I add these user permissions to my members_app_member_user_permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django handles all the associations in the Auth App, so you don't have to worry about the tables much.. just know that Group<->User relations are Many-2-Many, and the relation is in a completely separate table.

Here's the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization

But also, here's the basics of Groups to get you started:

##### Add a Single User to a Single Group

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, User

user_obj = User.objects.get(username='nealiumj')
group_obj = Group.objects.get(name='The Cool Kids')

# From Group object
group_obj.user_set.add(user_obj)

# From User Object
user_obj.groups.add(group_obj)
```

---

##### Has/In Group

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group

user_obj = User.objects.get(username='nealiumj')
has_group = user_obj.groups.filter(name='Lame').exists()

print(has_group)  # False!

##

group_obj = Group.objects.get(name='Lame')
in_group = group_obj.user_set.filter(name='nealiumj').exists()

print(in_group)  # Also False! ;)
```

---

You can also add multiple users to a single group or add multiple groups to a single user using the `*`

##### `*` adding. Multiple

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, User

user_obj_list = User.objects.get(username__in=['nealiumj','also_me'])
group_obj = Group.objects.get(name='The Cool Kids')

# Multiple users to a single group
group_obj.user_set.add(*user_obj_list)

###

user_obj = User.objects.get(username='nealiumj')
group_obj_list = Group.objects.get(name__in=['The Cool Kids', 'Super Attractive'])

# Multiple groups to a single user
user_obj.groups.add(*group_obj_list)
```

---

I persume because your `Member` model is inheriting the `User` one, that all of these methods will be avaliable from the `Member` Objects as well

Comment: Thank you, these group commands are what I needed to solve my issue. I was just confused because the database tables are setup in an odd way.